# Ocaml, why this code does not work?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec prime : int -> bool
 = fun n -> let rec f a = if (a = 1) then 1 
                       else if (n mod a) = 0 then 0 
                       else if ((f a-1) = 1) then 1 
                       else 0 
                       in 
                       if ((f n-1) = 1) then true 
                       else false
```

As you can see from my code, I want to implement a function which can tell given number is prime or not.

I can compile and run this code, but for all X function tell "false".

Why this happens?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I recommend to always add white spaces around binary operators. You get less confused by writing `f n - 1` than `f n-1` which many beginners misread as `f (n-1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
f n-1
```

is parsed like this:

```
(f n) - 1
```

You need to write this:

```
f (n - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((f n-1) = 1)
```

`f n-1` is equivalent to `(f n) - 1`, not `f (n - 1)`. So you're taking a number that's either 0 or 1, then subtract 1 from (yielding either -1 or 0) and then seeing whether it's 1, which it can never be.

Note that this wouldn't even have compiled had you made `f` return a boolean rather than an integer (you can't subtract from a boolean).